# Matrix with respect to basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Define D:$\wp_{2}$($\mathbb{R}$) $\mapsto$$\wp_{2}$($\mathbb{R}$)
>   by $D(p)(x) = p'(x)$ , Find the matrix of $D$ with respect to the basis
>   $\{1, 1+x, 1+x+x^2 \}$

I was thinking this would be the matrix $\left(\begin{array}[t]{ccc}
0 & 1 & 2\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$ by differentiating each of the terms in the basis, 
but i have a feeling this is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's wrong. Notice that  you should write the image of the polynomials in the given basis i.e.
$$D(1+x)=1$$
and 
$$D(1+x+x^2)=1+2x=2(1+x)-1$$
so the second column of the matrix is $(1,0,0)^T$ and the third column is $(-1,2,0)^T$.